# How can i find a particular index in a heap in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a vector array a = {1,12,12,6,5}. If i create a max heap than it will return me 12 as a first element. How do i know that the returned 12 is the 2nd or 3rd element of array a? I need the index of the returned element. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `std::pair<int, int>` array, where `first` element is an actual value and `second` is an index in initial array. Then, create a heap on this array and get the element index of the top element with `maxHeapElement.second`.

But remember, that it will always show you the right-most element of the same value since `std::pair` is compared lexicographical.